# Netbeans 7 Jboss 7 development setup

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss

I just switched from eclipse to Netbeans 7, and I try to deploy an ear to Jboss 7.1.1.

I cant figure out how to hot deploy static resource such css/JSF, and also when running the project it deploys to my jboss, but always as an archive. How do I deploy it unpacked ?

The project is using maven.

Best Regards

Comment: it will deploy a war, what else you want to deploy? :\

Comment: It deploys a .ear but I want an exploder ear

Comment: ah right, so.. what do you want exactly to achieve? this might help you http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch02s01.html

Comment: i mean the link is indicative of what you can deploy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can find, not possible to do an incremental deploy with Netbeans and JBoss.

Source: [Bug 199073](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199073)

Comment: Aha, that seems to be the same problem I have then. 
Thanks for the link.